# Pre-allocate drive space for lucene.net?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

When adding many records to a Lucene.Net database, the data files slowly increment in size.  This has the unwanted side effect of causing a lot of disk fragmentation on systems that have many Lucene databases and change them frequently.

My question is this:  Is there a way to pre-allocate hard drive space for a Lucene.Net DB to reduce the fragmentation?

If it matters, I'm coding in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a custom Directory implementation that would store the data in a larger pre-allocated file.

There's already a project named [big-dir](http://code.google.com/p/big-dir/) that does this for Lucene, the java version, which you could port to C#. It's in early alpha stage, according to their page, but their idea of creating a virtual file system within a file container seems like a working solution for you.